# VB.net session variable counter not adding on

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session-variables

I have a master page with the following vb code in the code file...

```
Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As EventArgs)

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        If Session("key") Is Nothing Then
            Session("key") = 0
        Else
            Session("key") = Session("key") + 1
        End If  
        Response.write(Session("key"))
        LoadData()
    End If

End Sub
```

This should write a number to the top of each page saying how many pages have been visited... It stays at zero all the time though.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to search your code in your master page and containing page for any `Session.Abandon()`

I ran into this problem a while back and didn't realise another developer had put that in.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested this and it works fine on my machine.

Ensure that your session timeout is set, otherwise it will expire resulting in `Session("key")` being set to 0 every `Page_Load`

Try adding the following to your web.config:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<sessionState timeout="120" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head:

Session state for other variables work correctly? Can you say `Session("A") = "ABC"` and retrieve that value from another page?

Anything returned from session is of type object - you may have to cast it, e.g. `Session("Key") = (Session("Key") As Int) + 1`.

LOL C#: `Session["Key"] = ((int)Session["Key"]) + 1;` - I'm staring to forget VB! Ha!